# Repeating “will” for two verbs with “and”

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs, repetition

I wanted to check if the phrase:

> The religious vandalism will spread and **will** contaminate many.

is correct according to English language grammar,

or whether the correct sentence is:

> The religious vandalism will spread and contaminate many.

Taken from the following Portuguese sentence, a prophecy from Our Lady:

> O vandalismo religioso se espalhará e contaminará a muitos.

Should I repeat *will* for the second verb, or write “The religious vandalism will spread and contaminate many”?

Comment: Drop *the* for idiomatic English. Beyond that, translation is off-topic here, though I will say that I very much doubt *vandalism* means the same thing to Iberians, who were occupied by the real Vandals, that it does in English.

Comment: @StoneyB It has the same meaning it has in English and Italian. It doesn't mean have any reference to Vandals. I would be surprised somebody would think of Vandals when speaking of _vandalismo_.

Comment: My question is: Is it correct to have the word WILL two times on that phrase?

Comment: @Tony Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified. IMO, this is valid also for translation questions. At the end, though, your question is not about translation, but about repeating _will_ for each verb. The fact you are translating a Portuguese sentence is secondary, which can let users understand from where you took the English sentence.

Comment: Answering here should not require users to know another language apart from English; you should ask the question in a way that is asking about alternative English phrases from where you think you can pick up the correct one, or about a English phrase you don't know, but for which you describe what you want to say, and in which context.

Comment: Would not be easier for you to answer if the WILL two times is correct or no? I put the original phrase for reference.

Comment: "defile" or "corrupt" or "pollute" may be a better translation of contaminar in this instance, since "contamination" is usually used in a more physical and literal sense in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may repeat *will* or not; both are grammatical. *Will* may be taken to 'distribute' over both infinitives, just as the subject does over both verb constructions.

The initial *the*, however, should be omitted. In English the definite article would be used only if a specific instance of vandalism were spoken of, and it appears from [this](http://motheofgod.com/threads/pedro-regis-messages-from-the-bvm.3871/page-10) source that this is  not the case here.

Comment: "Religious vandalism will spread and contaminate many."