# Using 'will' twice

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I am currently making a lesson plan and I have to put this sentence, but I'm not confident about its grammar correctness.

"Students will photograph their works and will post them on the subject’s official Messenger group chat."

Is using the word 'will' twice correct?

Comment: More specifically - Does this answer your question? [Repeating “will” for two verbs with “and”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11171/repeating-will-for-two-verbs-with-and)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I think it is grammatically correct, but dropping the second "will" is definitely more natural. Also, "works" should be "work," and "them" should be "it".

Comment: Thank you very much!